# In Microsoft Office Access 2013 how can I use my mouse wheel to advance to the next record?

Tags: microsoft-access, mouse-wheel

I am trying to set up Microsoft Access 2013 to advance to the next record by using my mouse wheel. My older version of Access allowed me to do this. How do I do it in the newest version of Access?

Answer (score 1):

*Note: My answer is assuming you are referring to Form view since you have not given much detail.*

Microsoft disabled this feature on purpose as explained in this support article - [You cannot use the mouse wheel to scroll through records in an Access 2007 or Access 2010 form](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2458709).

> The mouse wheel behavior in Form View was intentionally changed in
>   Access 2007 and in Access 2010 to reduce user confusion. In earlier
>   versions of Access, the mouse wheel would sometimes move the scroll
>   bar, or the mouse wheel would move records up or down. The mouse wheel
>   behavior is now consistent and only moves the scroll bar. There is no
>   property to change this behavior.

The article gives a VBA workaround, but it does not mention compatibility with 2013. You will have to try it and post another question if you have problems.